# Eclipse, subclipse and JAR dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, subclipse

Currently I'm doing a school project with 8 people. We're all running Eclipse with the SVN-plugin Subclipse installed. I decided to try out the MigLayout library for GUI-design, but I can't figure out how to include it in my project so that everyone who checks out (SVN) automatically gets the required dependency. What would be best practice?

Answer (score 2):

Create a `lib` directory inside the project and then put inside the jar lib, so you can add it to the build path and have it in your SVN repository.